# import cv2 error occured after installing opencv on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python, opencv

After installing OpenCV3.2.0 with the contrib modules on Ubuntu following this way：
http://www.samontab.com/web/2017/06/installing-opencv-3-2-0-with-contrib-modules-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

I run the python samples code:

```
cd <opencv3.2.0_dir>/samples/python/
python asift.py
```

and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "asift.py", line 26, in <module>
import cv2
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_freetype.so.3.2: undefined symbol: hb_shape
```

Running other python samples will get the same error.

I haven't found the answer in google. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That's a [known bug in the contrib modules](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/919), specifically in the freetype module, which allows you to draw UTF-8 strings.

Before compiling OpenCV 3.2, run this command:

```
sed -i 's/${freetype2_LIBRARIES} ${harfbuzz_LIBRARIES}/${FREETYPE_LIBRARIES} ${HARFBUZZ_LIBRARIES}/g' ../opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules/freetype/CMakeLists.txt
```

After that, you should be able to run the Python samples.

I also updated the tutorial you linked to include this fix by the way.